# Ubuntu 16.04: unattended task eating CPU

Tags: 16.04, cpu

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop; at random times, a task named "unattended+" uses 100% of one of the CPUs. I must be root in order to kill that process.

[screen shot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIelr.png)

My questions are:

1) what is the role of "unattended+"?

2) what can I do in order to permanently stop this task?

Comment: Can you post results of "top" into the question when this happens? (run "top", control-x and then copy/paste the text into the question)

Comment: I added a screen shot of the result of top to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this answer in another post.  Apparently with 16.04 an automatic apt-get update & upgrade that is performed twice a day.  https://github.com/chef/bento/issues/609

I have not addressed this problem on my install as yet, but wanted to relay this information.

dpkg and apt-get were unlocked on my install after a 5 minute delay after startup.

Comment: This issue was causing Ubuntu to not install git, displaying the following error message: `Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`. So I following the **@waltinator**'s comment on [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/15433/834395) and it worked for me. Basically, you kill the process using this tool so you can use it. This is not a solution for this question but it is related to the topic and eventually it will be suitable for those who need it.